# SQL for WP to delete users with multiple meta keys and comments

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I need help putting together an SQL that can to remove users if they don't have (metakey1 or metakey2) and (does not have comments)

I have this SQL which does it for single meta_key

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_users LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta
ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'metakey1'
WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id IS NULL
```

How can i extend the above SQL to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in` in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM wp_users u LEFT JOIN
     wp_usermeta um
     ON u.ID = um.user_id AND
        um.meta_key IN ('metakey1', 'metakey2', 'comments')
WHERE um.user_id IS NULL;
```

You get no matches only if *all* the metakeys are missing, which I think is what you are asking for.

EDIT:

You seem to want:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM wp_users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM wp_usermeta um
                  WHERE u.ID = um.user_id AND
                        um.meta_key IN ('metakey1', 'metakey2')
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM wp_comments c
                  WHERE u.ID = c.user_id
                 );
```

I prefer `NOT EXISTS` if you are going to have multiple comparisons to different tables.

Comment: Acually @Gordon the comments is not a usermeta! so the SQL above does it for the metakeys 1 and 2 but how can we also check if the user has posted a comment on the site?

Comment: So we also need to check in the wp_comments table for the comment_author_email column if the value is empty

Comment: @GuruSurfer . . . Fix your question to address what the data actually looks like.

Comment: my question clearly point that i am trying to delete users who does not have metakeys 1 and 2 and who do not have comments. I can only think of ways to paraphrase so here it is:

An SQL to check if the user does not have usermeta metakey1 and metakey2 and who did not post comments in wp_comments 

Hope this is more clear, and super thanks for the support here :)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a delete with an exists clause asserting the requirement of either of two keys:

```
DELETE
FROM wp_users wp1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_usermeta wp2
                  WHERE wp1.ID = wp2.user_id AND
                        wp2.meta_key IN ('metakey1', 'metakey2'));
```

Note that the following where clause is no longer needed in the version of the query I wrote above:

```
WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id IS NULL
```

It is no longer needed because `NOT EXISTS` now handles the job which the exclusion join was handling previously.

Comment: @Strawberry Are you kidding me?  I did just have two shots of Auchentosen, but...I mean come on here...

Comment: Facepalm.  What threw me off was that the exclusion column was also what appeared in the join.  In any case, I don't think my answer needs to change because of this.